# Creating Table View From Firebase Query (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a search bar in order to populate a table view based on a search query. I'm simply looking for usernames here.

Data structure:

```
"Users"
  -"UID"
    -"Username"
```

I've got a query running for text typed into the search bar. I can print the results of the search just fine, so I know they're coming back. However, *I cannot breakout the data from the query closure and don't know what to do*

I tried building an internal array and then just setting the external array to it, but it always contains zero values. I know my for-loop is running and I know values are being returned. They're just not being saved.

```
        self.filteredNameList = []
    let searchText = searchText.lowercased()
    let userQuery = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: searchText)

    userQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let name = userDict["username"] as! String
            self.filteredNameList.append(name)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("Inside closure: \(self.filteredNameList)")
    })
    print("Outside closure: \(self.filteredNameList)")
}
```

What should I do? Thanks - Keenan

Comment: Posted an example answer, but in your structure you've got an upper case U in Username and the key you are querying is a lower case u in username.

Comment: Oh yeah that's my bad I just forgot to lowercase it in my example. The keys match up. Good insight though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tested example

Given a firebase structure

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "bill"
  uid_1
    name: "leroy"
  uid_2
    name: "frank"
  uid_3
    name: "leon"
```

and we want to return all nodes starting with 'le' and store them in an array

```
var namesArray = [String]() //note this is stored outside the function so other
                            //functions can access it.

func getSomeLe() {
  self.namesArray = [] //init it any time this func is called.
  let usersRef = ref.child("users")
  let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryStarting(atValue: "le")

    queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

      for snap in snapshot.children {
          let userSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
          let uid = userSnap.key
          let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
          let name = userDict["name"] as! String
          self.namesArray.append(name)
      }
      print(self.namesArray)
  })
}
```

stores the data in the array and prints

["leroy","leon"]

Comment: "getSomeLe()" Had me laughing. I appreciate the humor. I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: I refactored my code to match your solution. I notice that your print statement is in the closure itself. When I print from within the closure, the name list is present. When I print from outside of the closure, however, the name list is empty entirely! What's going on? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: That's because your print statement is probably right after your call to load the items from Firebase. That won't work (sometimes) as Firebase is asynchronous and it takes time for firebase to retrieve the data and present it inside the closure. So your print statement in code executes way faster than receiving data from the internet. You should move on to the 'next step' from within the closure - like presenting a view controller or working with the data.

Comment: Right. However, I simply have a table view that display the retrieved data. I have tableView.reloadData() inside of the closure. Therefore, shouldn't it refresh itself with the retrieved names after the asynchronous call is complete? Nothing is displayed.

Comment: I figured it out. Stupid thing. The result was hidden in the first cell behind the search bar. Unbelievable. Thanks for the help, Jay. I really appreciate it!